# Как добавить класс активности в бесконечном слайдере swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Кто знает, как правильно работать с добавлением класса активности в бесконечном слайдере [swiper](https://swiperjs.com)?

Код: [codepen](https://codepen.io/sadmearise/pen/abqKbmN)

Есть слайдер, если при инициализации слайдера установить параметр бесконечности `loop: false`, то он будет работать так, как задумано, а именно: если на одном из слайдов мы кликнем по кубику - он станет синим и на этом слайде будет синим до тех пор, пока мы не кликнем по нему ещё раз.
Теперь возвращаем параметр отвечающий за бесконечность слайдера в положение `true` и слайдер ломается. На первом слайде мы кликаем на кубик и он окрашивается в синий, нажимаем вперед и переходим на второй слайд, как и ожидалось, кубик красный, нажимаем далее и переходим на первый слайд и кубик становится красным, а не как ожидалось синим. Это возникает по причине создания дублирующих слайдов свайпером. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при бесконечном слайдере он отрабатывал так же как и при обычном?

Однажды я сталкивался с подобным, но решил эту проблему как мне показалось костылём(прописал кучу условий), поэтому сейчас ищу более изящное решение.

Answer (score 0):

На одном из форумов подсказали, что можно добавить класс активности для всех элементов с одинаковым атрибутом `data-swiper-slide-index`. И это сработало!